# REST API System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, string, input

I've encountered a strange problem with Rest API. I use it to collect data from SharePoint to my report. It works fine for all libraries on my site except for one. String that I use:

```
https://<my site>/services/_api/web/Lists(guid'144bef91-f287-47f7-9ccb-6b4ffcf71b00')/Items
```

Funny thing is that:

```
 https://<my site>/services/_api/web/Lists(guid'144bef91-f287-47f7-9ccb-6b4ffcf71b00')
```

is returning a proper response with no errors at all.

Browser error message shows a 500 internal server message, logs show *System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format* error.

This site was updated from SP2010 to SP2013 using automated script - I wonder if this could be a root cause?

Comment: Could you try to get items with list name instead Guid and check if working http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items

Comment: Hello, Unfortunately, it didn't work at all.  I got the same response:
The website cannot display the page
  HTTP 500 
Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

Answer (score 0):

After I got more information from logs (I'm a site admin, I do not have access to farm administration) I've found out that one of the lookup columns was causing problems.

Log data:

```
The field value for field DocTechnology of type Lookup cannot be serialized. Value=#ERR, Exception=System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.     at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)     at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)     at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.GetFieldValueAsNonLookup(String fieldName, SPListItemEntityMetadata metadata)   1df5139e-eb1b-c0cb-a010-9e8b28f1e88f
Exception occured in scope Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem._SerializeToOData. Exception=System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Solution: delete column & add it again. Fortunately, I didn't have much to fill after this operation.